# Linker Error when using a Singleton in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, linker, singleton, linker-errors

I'm getting the **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)** error when attempting to instantiate a singleton.

Here is the code I've been using to make my class a singleton:

.h

```
@interface CoursesManager : NSObject
{

}
+ (id)SharedInstance;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation CoursesManager

+ (id)SharedInstance
{
     static dispatch_once_t once;
     static id sharedInstance;
     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
     sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
     });

     return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

And this is how I've been using it in other classes:

```
coursesManager = [CoursesManager SharedInstance];
```

After looking a little more into it, it seems that simply importing this file in other .m's causes the linker error.  I'm pretty confused as to what could be causing this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Just for reference, I'm using Xcode 4.3.3.

**EDIT full comments of the error are as follows:**

ld: duplicate symbol _MAX_COURSES in ../Objects-normal/armv7/CourseEditorViewController.o and .../Objects-normal/armv7/CourseSelectionViewController.o for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Above @interface CoursesManager, I've declared two const int variables, MAX_COURSES and MAX_HOLES.

Comment: Can you please include the full contents of the error?

Comment: Sure thing.  I've just edited the question to include those.

Comment: And therein was my problem.  Changing the const int variables to #define fixed the linker error.  I'm not really sure why, but I'm happy that it's fixed.

What should I do about this whole question now?  Leave it as is?  Remove it?  Answer my own question?  What is standard procedure for something like this?

Comment: I updated my response to offer solutions as well as an explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `@end` at the end of your implementation in `CourseManager.m`?

Are you importing any files in your `CourseManager.h` file? If so, make sure none of the files you are importing have an import statement for `CourseManager.h` in them (i.e. two files importing each other).

FYI, This is the recommended and thread-safe way to create a singleton:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

**Update**

The error came because @rkeller was declaring `const int` values in his CourseManager.h file and then importing that .h file into a few other files.

To avoid this, there are a few things you can do:

1. switch `const int` to `#define`
2. switch `const int` to `static const int`
3. declare the value in `CourseManager.h` as `extern const int MyConstant`  and then instantiate the value in `CourseManager.m` like so: `const int MyConstant = 0;`

When you declare a non-static constant in the header file, the compiler treats that constant as an independent global for each file that imports that header file. Then, when the linker tries to link all of the compiled sources, it will encounter the global numerous times -- hence the linker error.

Comment: Yes, I do have the @end at the end of the .m file (had to double-check to make sure.)  And no I was very diligent about not having any circular inclusion so that isn't the problem.

Thanks for the tip about the thread safe creation though. :)

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that simply importing this file in other .m's causes the linker error.

You can't do that.  Your file has a static variable in it and the implementation. The static variable isn't a problem for the linker since each and every .m file you import it in will have its own instance of `cm` (not what you want though) but you'll also get duplicate `@implementation`s which is probably what's causing the linker error.

Put the interface into a header file and import that everywhere.  The implementation and the static variable go in a separate `.m` file.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, but I think your solution is based off of my lack of detail in the question.  The @implementation line and everything below it are located in CoursesManager's .m file.  I'll edit that so it makes more sense.